# ¿Como puedo restaurar mis clases java a su estado original?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

el día de hoy estaba abriendo un proyecto de android studio en el cual estaba trabajando, pero tardo tiempo en  abrir completamente y solo mostraba el  mensaje de `indexing paused due to batch update android studio files damage` entonces lo abri nuevamente y algunas clases no cargaron como deberian, aparecieron  de la sigiente forma en formato xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="RtlOverlay.DialogWindowTitle.AppCompat" parent="Base.DialogWindowTitle.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:textAlignment">viewStart</item>
    </style>
    <style name="RtlOverlay.Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TitleItem" parent="android:Widget">
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_vertical|start</item>
        <item name="android:paddingEnd">8dp</item>
    </style>
    <style name="RtlOverlay.Widget.AppCompat.DialogTitle.Icon" parent="android:Widget">
        <item name="android:layout_marginEnd">8dp</item>
    </style>
    <style name="RtlOverlay.Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenuItem" parent="android:Widget">
        <item name="android:paddingEnd">16dp</item>
    </style>
    <style name="RtlOverlay.Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenuItem.InternalGroup" parent="android:Widget">
        <item name="android:layout_marginStart">16dp</item>
    </style>
    <style name="RtlOverlay.Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenuItem.Text" parent="android:Widget">
        <item name="android:layout_alignParentStart">true</item>
        <item name="android:textAlignment">viewStart</item>
    </style>
    <style name="RtlOverlay.Widget.AppCompat.Search.DropDown" parent="android:Widget">
        <item name="android:paddingStart">@dimen/abc_dropdownitem_text_padding_left</item>
        <item name="android:paddingEnd">4dp</item>
    </style>
    <style name="RtlOverlay.Widget.AppCompat.Search.DropDown.Icon1" parent="android:Widget">
        <item name="android:layout_alignParentStart">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="RtlOverlay.Widget.AppCompat.Search.DropDown.Icon2" parent="android:Widget">
        <item name="android:layout_toStartOf">@id/edit_query</item>
    </style>
    <style name="RtlOverlay.Widget.AppCompat.Search.DropDown.Query" parent="android:Widget">
        <item name="android:layout_alignParentEnd">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="RtlOverlay.Widget.AppCompat.Search.DropDown.Text" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.DropDownItem.Spinner">
        <item name="android:layout_toStartOf">@android:id/icon2</item>
        <item name="android:layout_toEndOf">@android:id/icon1</item>
    </style>
    <style name="RtlOverlay.Widget.AppCompat.SearchView.MagIcon" parent="android:Widget">
        <item name="android:layout_marginStart">@dimen/abc_dropdownitem_text_padding_left</item>
    </style>
    <style name="RtlUnderlay.
```

y no se como restaurarlas cabe mencionar que estoy usando:

- android studio 3.2.1
- Git

Espero y me puedan orientar en como resolverlo, gracias mientras tanto seguiré investigando.
Saludos

Comment: has probado `clean project` y `rebuild`

Comment: tenes commits guardados de versiones no muy viejas? Si no podes desde android studio, ahora comento la respuesta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te sugiero realizar la invalidación de caché en Android Studio y reiniciar.**

`File` > `Invalidate Cache / Restart`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de esta forma tu proyecto se creara nuevamente, al parecer hubo un error en la sincronización por eso muestra las clases como .xml

en caso de que aparezca el mensaje:

"indexing paused due to batch update" simplemente da clic en el botón [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias, lo intente ya varias veces y no  ha podido recuperar todos los archivos, y he empezado a recuperar algunos con versiones  de commits pasados

Comment: acabo de revisar desde el explorer de windows y lo abrí con  visual studio code y ahí si están bien los archivos pero con la opcion de "invalidate caches/restart" no me funciona

Comment: Ya lo corregí, fue actualizando el android studio, y ahora si pudo  eliminar invalidar el cache completamente

Answer (score 0):

Para volver un commit anterios primero debes guardar tus cambios actuales

```
git add .
git commit -am "VOLVERE ATRAS"
```

Luego, debes ver los commits que tenes localmente (porlomenos para este ejemplo, tambien puedes bajarte commits en la nube)

```
git log
```

Deberian aparecerte lso commits con iformacion parecida a esta:

> commit 26580302472aee0ff813528176679671b24d6d90 (HEAD -> master,
>   origin/master, origin/HEAD) Author: LcsGrz <-----> Date:   Mon Feb 18
>   01:04:26 2019 -0300
>
> ```
> STARTUP FIX
> ```

Luego para volver al commit anterior deberas introducir

```
git checkout HASH_DE_TU_COMMIT .
```

No olvides poner el punto al final
Tambien podes volver commits atras borrando los que le siguen, con

```
git reset --hard HEAD~N   --> N numero de commits que quieres volver atras
```

Si decides no hacer esto desde git, desde android studio tenes un control de versionado
Podes acceder a el desde la clase que queres volver atras:

> Click derecho -> Local History -> Show History

En imagen por las dudas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me parece que no se refiere a esto, Android Studio no sincronizo completamente y las clases .java se muestran ahora como xml

Comment: @Jorgesys creo en tu respuesta por que nunca me paso, pensaria que la solucion es revertir D:

Comment: quizas podría ser una solución revertir los archivos,  pero me parece que el problema sucede en la IDE a mi me ha sucedido, imagina que ves archivos .java y al tratar de editarlos se muestra solo .xml :-/ un poco raro, no lo había visto en otra IDE.

Comment: Terrible problemon, entre que es muy loco e inusual seguro que lo primero que pensas es que perdiste todo el trabajo que hiciste durante todo este tiempo D:. Un golaso que lo pudiste arreglar y compartir la solucion. Demomento dejo mi respuesta activa por las dudas, asi tiene una segunda opcion